# Mediawiki won't work because of httpd start error

Tags: linux, mediawiki

My mediawiki install in httpd server for more than two years，today I get the following error when i restart httpd

```
    Unable to verify certificate 'Server-Cert'. Add "NSSEnforceValidCerts off" to nss.conf so the server can start until the problem can be resolved.
```

I solve this by add NSSEnforceValidCerts off in nss.conf in the conf.d folder.But   httpd still won't start with  following error:

```
   [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 8443, the first has precedence (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 8443
```

how to solve it? thanks

Comment: check port 8443 already in use somewhere ?

Comment: I use lsof -i:8443 to check , did not find any process use the port

Comment: @snow8261 please provide your virtualhost configuration to get good understanding of your problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in my case was to comment the following lines out of the /etc/httpd/conf.d/nss.conf file:

```
#LoadModule nss_module modules/libmodnss.so
#Listen 8443
```

service httpd start 
and it works again!
thanks for all!